# Custom parameters of a callback function depending of event

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback, parameter-passing

How can I custom the parameter of callback function like this :

```
//THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
object = {
  x : 20,
  y : 10,
  on : (event,callback)=>{
    //What stuff can I do here 
    //to customize my callback parameters depending of the event
    //so that I can exploit this parameter later
    //like $.on('click',function(param)) on jQuery 
  }
};

object.on('send',(param)=>{
  //and here depending of event='send' this variable param 
  //is returned by the other definition of "object"..
});
```

What stuff can I do here to customize my **callback parameters** *depending* of the **event** so that I can exploit this parameter later like `$.on('click',function(param))` on jQuery.

If something is not clear **please** ask me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have a single parameter, that is in fact a JSON object, this would allow you to have different keys in different situations.

Comment: I think you are approaching this from the wrong angle, it's not good practice for single function to not know what types it's params are going to be. Create 2 different methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's what i mean i solve my probleme and thanks :

```
object = {
  x : 20,
  y : 10,
  on : function(event,callback){
    switch(event){
      case 'get' : callback({'x':this.x,'y':this.y});break;
      case 'multiple': callback(this.x*this.y);break;
      case 'addition': callback(this.x+this.y);break;
      default : callback('No event passed');
    }
  }
};

object.on('get',(param)=>{
  console.log(param);//Object { x: 20, y: 10 }
});
```